# How to return an array as object in PHP?

Tags: php

```
function myfunc ()
{
    $a['foo'] = 'bar';
    $a['baz'] = 'qux';

    return $a;
}
```

How do you do it so that when you call `$a = myfunc();` you can use `echo $a->foo;` and it will output `bar`?

Additional question: Having that simple function above, is it better to return an array or object?

Comment: "Better" is subjective. Better for what purpose?

Comment: @deceze I guess my question is what is more efficient in terms of use of system resources in the same comparison that single quotes is faster than double quotes.

Comment: @IMB: Have a look at this: http://www.phpbench.com/

Comment: @Rocket That site is interesting, but mostly missing the point. `isset` vs. `empty` vs. `is_array` is entirely pointless, for instance, since they all do very different things and are used in different situations. Don't choose which to use based on minuscule performance differences.

Comment: @deceze: I was mostly trying to show that single vs double quotes is silly and you shouldn't worry.

Comment: @RocketHazmat double quotes is slower because you type `SHIFT + "` instead of just `'` :-)

Comment: @IMB: Well, you got me there :-P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just cast it as an object.

```
function myfunc ()
{
    $a['foo'] = 'bar';
    $a['baz'] = 'qux';

    return (object)$a;
}
```

As for which one you want, it's up to you.  It depends on what you are doing with the returned object or array.

Answer (score 1):

1-I would do it like this :

```
function myfunc ()
{
    $a['foo'] = 'bar';
    $a['baz'] = 'qux';
    $array = new ArrayObject($a);
    return $array;
}
```

[ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) is supported form php version 5

2- doesn't really matter if you return array or object , its your decision

Answer (score 0):

If you return an array you will have to access the member as `$a['foo']`. The `->` is indeed an oop operator. To use this you would need to create an object instead of an array, *but* that means you have to define a class first. This again means that the two members `foo` and `baz` must be present for *all* instanciations of such an object. So that is a completely different thing.